# webbrowser control with memory increasing problem

Tags: c#

i have a program that navigate  the urls links one by one when it open a page it increase the memory usages and continue increasing .i found after two or three hour it occupied 1 and half gb of my memory to open a hunderd pages how can i fix this problem.

Comment: Can you paste your code? It sounds like you are saving some resource and releasing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904478/how-to-fix-the-memory-leak-in-ie-webbrowser-control#905063) to [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904478/how-to-fix-the-memory-leak-in-ie-webbrowser-control), the memory increases at each page request/load, but will be released in a while - which means it is actually not a memory leak. Try to minimize the application window - is the memory released then?

In that case, you could try to trim the working set of the application periodically through this code (from [this forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/88c21427-e765-46e8-833d-6021ef79e0c8), the answer by mike_t2e):

```
// In class definition
[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SetProcessWorkingSetSize", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern bool SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr pProcess, int dwMinimumWorkingSetSize, int dwMaximumWorkingSetSize);

[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentProcess", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

// ...

// Call this when you want to trim the working set
IntPtr pHandle = GetCurrentProcess();
SetProcessWorkingSetSize(pHandle, -1, -1);
```

Comment: Hi Anders Fjeldstad,

Thanks for your support.

Regards,
Manish.

Comment: This doesn't really work. I did a test, check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147923/webbrowser-memory-problem

Comment: This worked for me! Handles getting released immediately.

Answer (score 2):

SetProcessWorkingSetSize doesn't actually release any memory.
It does incease the probabilty of the memory being paged out to disk,
and probably cause a GC collect.

I don't understand background workings of WebBrowser control, but I've realised one thing:

My program goes through 500 or more pages and reads new content on them. It hogs the RAM
quite quickly, and if I run the same function that runs through all those pages again, it simply reads from webbrowser cache, cause it needs only couple of seconds to complete.

It means that we only need to clear browser cache in order to free RAM. Right? I found
this solution, but it doesn't work.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326201/en-us

It allways gives me PrtectedMemoryException...

Ok, so how is it possible that the memory is freed only when I close my application, and
it's not freed when i dispose my webbrowser control and create new one?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to execute the code that resource provides.

Answer (score 0):

RT _> It allways gives me `ProtectedMemoryException`.

Either change your platform to `x86` from project properties -> build or replace

`returnValue = DeleteUrlCacheEntry(internetCacheEntry.lpszSourceUrlName);`

with **internetCacheEntry.lpszLocalFileName**.