# Does GeckoFX has all the functionality of a .NET WebBrowser?

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control, gecko

I'm considering using the GeckoFX component instead of a WebBrowser because of a memory leak (You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147923/webbrowser-memory-problem), [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/88c21427-e765-46e8-833d-6021ef79e0c8) and [this](http://blog.j15r.com/2005/01/dhtml-leaks-like-sieve.html) regarding the leak) that doesn't have a solution.

The problem is that my application uses `WebBrowser`'s [`InvokeScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.HTMLDOCUMENT.INVOKESCRIPT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) with parameters. I'm pretty sure there is no `InvokeScript` in GeckoFX and seems that people use `Navigate("javascript:stuff()")` instead. I'm not sure how am I going to send parameters that way.

But even if there is a workaround, is it really possible to use GeckoFX instead of a WebBrowser without loosing all the functionality?

I don't want to start this tedious job and then find out that it wasn't possible because of some GeckoFX limitation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you are calling a "memory leak" is just the result of non-deterministic memory collection... There's no reason to solve problems that don't exist. Profiling using Task Manager is a fool's errand. And you're not likely to "solve" the problem by switching to an alternative browser control.

Comment: You can call it many ways, and the task manager can show many things, but it makes the application unresponsive and sometimes causes OutOfMemory exceptions. I posted a sample code so people can repro: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147923/webbrowser-memory-problem

Answer (score 0):

Geckofx 14 is way better than .NET WebBrowser which depends on IE version on user machine

Geckofx has complete DOM manipulation so you can create script tag and place javascript code inside instead of Navigate("javascript:stuff()")

I think Geckofx is best solution for .NET <= 3.5
current Geckofx 14 is equivalent to Firefox 14 so it support large scale of web standards

if you're using .NET 4.0 you may consider switching to http://awesomium.com/ which is WebKit powered