# Replace WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser(); with Chrome instance instead of using ie

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, watin

I'm working with an aplication that embeds a WebBrowser control into a windows form and I'm noticing a serious memory leak issue. After reading about other similiar cases around the internet the problem seems to be native to IE.

I've asked how others have solved this and one person reported shipping a gecko wrapper with his software. I've done some investigating, but it does not look like I'll be able to use WatiN,  (which is what my software makes use of) with anything but Internet Explorer and Firefox 3.5  and they also say watin can integrate with Chrome (experimentally, though I can't find any documentation).

Does anyone have any experience with this issue and know how I should go about providing a solution that will work on multiple platforms?

Does firefox 11 have the ability to revert to 3.5? Has anyone successfully used WatiN inside a windows form with a browser other than Internet Explorer... and even better, has anyone found out how to discard the IE memory build up that seems to go unanswered in all the documented threads I've read about (best one being here so far: [How to Fix the Memory Leak in IE WebBrowser Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904478/how-to-fix-the-memory-leak-in-ie-webbrowser-control))

Thanks for helping me with this topic!

Comment: Selenium in the last couple of releases has come up to par with Watin.  Guess thats something you didn't want to hear. But +1 for the good question it reminds me of this question put to Steve Ballmer at this conference: http://www.techworld.com.au/article/266449/microsoft_interested_open_source_browser_ballmer/#closeme 3rd paragraph

Comment: Heya Jeremy,  My block with Selenium was the inability to add the browser to a windows form. If they ever add a connectable way to do this I'll definitely consider the switch. I've been able to do things with the Selenium IDE that I haven't been able to do with Watin.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [GeckoFX (https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx/wiki/Version_lists)](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx/wiki/Version_lists).  Seems to support/include MANY (even FF11) versions.  Comes with examples and full source.

The previous version of  GeckoFX is a stale version, don't accidentally use the one located at code.google.com/p/geckofx/.

Comment: Hey Erik, How will this work out with Watin? I'm in desparate need of compatibility sense I've built my system with it.

Comment: It litterally uses the Firefox engine, and I only linked it because you stated that WatiN only works with Internet Explorer and Firefox 3.5.  I have no experience with WatiN but I would assume that if you used GeckoFX (which is FF 3.6) you have a very good possiblity of compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Or the alternative to GeckoFX is http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hey Jeremy, I've the same as I did for GeckFX. Compatibility with watin is something I'm looking for help on.