# Memory Leak in IE WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, memory-leaks, watin

In C# I use as a web-browser control ( Watin browser control ) where I run this control into another thread of the main thread.

After a few hours, a memory leak is created.

There is another post ( here : [How to Fix the Memory Leak in IE WebBrowser Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904478/how-to-fix-the-memory-leak-in-ie-webbrowser-control) or [How to get around the memory leak in the .NET Webbrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302933/how-to-get-around-the-memory-leak-in-the-net-webbrowser-control)) that suggests to call "`SetProcessWorkingSetSize`" from `KERNEL32.DLL`.

The workaround is to minimize the winform of web-browser control.

So my question is: if there is another way to solve this problem? and if not, if I use an alternative web-browser control like mozilla-gecko I will solve this memory-leak.

Comment: we had similiar issue.
Maybe my answer helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/24465159/3581404

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to call the garbage collector & force the Windows OS to clean the memory. For example into finally you can write :

```
finally
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    EmptyWorkingSet(GetCurrentProcess());
}
```

`EmptyWorkingSet` forces the OS to clean the memory.