# C# Web Browser Component Memory Leak

Tags: c#, javascript, memory-leaks

logHopefully someone can help.

I've added a web browser component to my form and I've noticed a memory leak when calling a JavaScript function repeatedly.

Every time I run (this command gets called every 2 - 3 seconds):

```
browser.Document.InvokeScript("TestFunction", new object[] { "Test", "Test" });
```

The memory just keeps rising until I get a crash with an out of memory warning.

Has anyone else noticed memory problems when invoking a script with an object?

UPDATE:

Added the test function I have been calling. The leak happens with any JS I call with arguments.

```
function TestFunction(var1, var2)
{
  console.log(var1 + " " + var2);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code of "TestFunction"

Comment: I will expect some tihng like this to happen if `TestFunction` holds a reference to the arguments, like puting them on an array somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Fix the Memory Leak in IE WebBrowser Control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904478/how-to-fix-the-memory-leak-in-ie-webbrowser-control)