# System.OutOfMemoryException unhandled exception?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, out-of-memory, webbrowser-control, unhandled-exception

I'm working on a C# project for windows phone 8 that plays selected youtube videos.My app has 1 page, which has 3 Grids (1 for each of 3 States).

1. Video Selection Menu (where I have an ItemsControl which has around 80-100 grids inside, where each of those grids has 2 textblocks, 1 image and a button inside them)
2. Video Details Menu (Shows more info about the video the user selected on the "Video Selection Menu" and has a play button which gets you to the third State).
3. Video (has a webbrowser control with the selected video)

Ok, about the problem now... When I have selected a video from State_1, then pressed play in State_2 that gets me to State_3 it's all ok. But when I go back to State_1 and start to scroll through the videos I get this exception: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll`

Do you have any idea on what is the problem or how to fix this?

NOTE:

1. Whenever a State changes I make `Visibility.Collapsed` the 2 other Grids and `Visibility.Visible` the Grid that the State variable states.
2. When I don't have a webbrowser in the app (so no State_3) it works fine no problems. So my guess is that I need to disable the memory allocation of webbrowser when I'm not using it but not sure how.

Call Stack:

1. >   MyappName.DLL!MyappName.App.Application_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 107 C# `Debugger.Break();`
2. System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.Error.CallApplicationUEHandler(System.Exception e)    Unknown
3. System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.JoltHelper.OnUnhandledException(object sender, System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)   Unknown
4. [Native to Managed Transition]
5. [Managed to Native Transition]
6. System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.NotifyManagedDebuggerOnNativeOOM() Unknown

Comment: Your program is attempting to allocate more memory than it has available to it. We'd have to see the code, but usually it happens when allocating objects (often in a loop) and not disposing of them properly. You should also post the call stack - that may show where this is happening specifically.

Comment: All my code is just the button_click events when you select a video which take theinfo from the 2 textblocks (title and description) I have in the grid the button was in and transferthe info to state_2 so that user can read it more clearly. a variable state which when it changes it makes other grids collapse and the one I want visible. and the code that changes the url of the webbrowser. That's it. I don't allocate any objects, and I don't have any loops. I added call Stack on the question :)